# IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008R2 - no "error pages"

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7.5

I have two boxes running IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008R2 64-bit. One of them has the "Error pages" setting (screenshot below), and the other one doesn't have this.

What feature/role service/thing am I missing in the one that doesn't have this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a role service under Web Server called `HTTP Error Pages` that I'd install if you don't already have it installed.[image]

Comment: Thanks... yes, I have that installed, still not showing up :(

Comment: I confirmed by removing that role service, doing an IIS reset, then re-adding the role service and doing an IIS reset that the role service is responsible for that particular icon.

Comment: As is so often the case with Windows :)